# How to import a SVG file and scale it using latest version of Blender

Tags: blend-files

I am a newbie with Blender (Version 2.83) on Windows 10. I want to do one simple job: import a SVG file and scale it in Blender.
I downloaded a football image in SVG file format, its name is like: C:\Temp\Football.svg
Now, I open Blender 2.83 and delete the default image, then I import the football SVG file, but I can't see it from Blender.
So I think it is small, maybe I can scale it to a little bigger.
I can type "Ctrl+A" and I can see Scale with number of 9.
But how I can scale it to something bigger?  For example, if I want to scale it to twice as bigger as now, which keys/mouse I have to use?
I have only 2-button mouse.
Please advice.
[image]

Comment: There is nothing different in newer versions of blender, it works just the same as the old. Select "Scale" and move the mouse to the right to make things bigger.

Answer (score 0):

To scale you need to select the object and press S. Then you can move the mouse to size the object.

Some useful shortcut are:

- S, then a number (for example: 3) --> you increase the object * 3 (you can also use non integer number, like 0.5)
- S, Z (or X or Y) --> you increase the object only in Z (or X or Y) axis
- S, SHIFT+Z (or SHIFT+X, SHIFT+Y) --> you increase the object in all directions but Z

Comment: Hello: I tried to do what you have instructed.  However, it seems not easy: you mean "select the object", which I don't know how to do this.  I typed S then 5 trying to make it 5 times of the original size.  But I can't see it.

Comment: To select the object you just need to left click on it (or select from the right panel where you have all your objects listed). You need to be in object mode (not in edit mode)